# Alguien que me apoye con una duda de vectores y matrices?

Tags: c

El problema que me piden es crear una matriz mxn, donde m=n y llenarla, de esa matriz me piden guardar en un vector las esquinas de la matriz, pero la forma en la que lo guarde creo que esta mal, el problema es que no se en que estoy fallando, el codigo me funciona en una matriz de 3x3, pero una matriz de 4 para arriba no me funciona el codigo, no se en que parte de la logica estoy fallando, alguien que me pueda ayudar por favor?:(

````
 #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>

    int main() {
    
    int m,f,c;
    printf("Ingrese el tama%co de la matriz (considere que es una matriz donde m==n)=",164);
    scanf("%d",&m);
    int matriz[m][m];
    int i, h;
    for(f=0;f<m;f++){
        for(c=0;c<m;c++){
            printf("Ingrese un numero para la posicion [%d][%d]=",f+1,c+1);
            scanf("%d",&matriz[f][c]);
        }
    }
    for(f=0;f<m;f++){
        for(c=0;c<m;c++){
            printf("%4d",matriz[f][c]);
        } printf("\n");
    }
    int vector[f*c];
    for(f=0;f<m;f++){
        for(c=0;c<m;c++){
            if(matriz[f][c]==matriz[0][0]){
                vector[h]=matriz[f][c];
                h=h+1;
            }
            if(matriz[f][c]==matriz[0][m-1]){
                vector[h]=matriz[f][c];
                h=h+1;
            }
            if(matriz[f][c]==matriz[m-1][0]){
                vector[h]=matriz[f][c];
                h=h+1;
            }
            if(matriz[f][c]==matriz[m-1][m-1]){
                vector[h]=matriz[f][c];
                h=h+1;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Esquinas de la matriz:\n");
    for(i=0;i<h;i++){
        printf("%4d",vector[i]);
    }
    return 0;
} ```
````

Comment: Pon un título _relevante_ en lugar de algo así como "alguien que me ayude con..." Recuerda que tanto la pregunta como las respuestas deben ser útiles no solo para ti, sino también para los demás miembros de la comunidad. Con el planteamiento actual, difícilmente alguien con un problema similar al tuyo encuentre la pregunta. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Debes darle un valor inicial a la variable `h = 0`

```
int i, h = 0;
```

Te presento una solución más resumida para encontrar las esquinas, sin recorrer todos los elementos de la matriz.Cambiar `acumulador++` del **for fila** y **for columna** del vector por `fila = fila + valorMaximo` y `columna = columna + valorMaximo`; la variable `valorMaximo` representa los valores máximos que puede tener cada fila y columna y su valor se da por `valorMaximo= m - 1;`. Con esto ya no necesitas preguntar cada posición si es una esquina.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    int m, fila, columna;
    printf("Ingrese el tama%co de la matriz (considere que es una matriz donde m==n)=", 164);
    scanf("%d", &m);
    int matriz[m][m];
    for (fila = 0; fila < m; fila++)
    {
        for (columna = 0; columna < m; columna++)
        {
            printf("Ingrese un numero para la posicion [%d][%d]=", fila + 1, columna + 1);
            scanf("%d", &matriz[fila][columna]);
        }
    }
    for (fila = 0; fila < m; fila++)
    {
        for (columna = 0; columna < m; columna++)
        {
            printf("%4d", matriz[fila][columna]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    int vector[m];
    int posicionVector = 0, valorMaximo = 0, valorMinimo = 0;
    valorMaximo = m - 1;
    
    printf("Esquinas de la matriz:\n");
    for (fila = 0; fila < m; fila = fila + valorMaximo)
    {
        for (columna = 0; columna < m; columna = columna + valorMaximo)
        {
            vector[posicionVector] = matriz[fila][columna];
            printf("%4d", vector[posicionVector]);
            posicionVector++;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```